# How can I create a multi-line wx.ComboCtrl in wxPython?

Tags: wxpython, wxwidgets, multiline

Setting the wx.TE_MULTILINE style flag on the ComboCtrl itself or the associated TextCtrl results in no change after a Refresh(). After quite some time Googling, I saw several sources that stated that apparently creating multiline Combo **Box** is complicated/impossible, yet creating a multi-line Combo **Ctrl** was simple enough that they didn't mention how it is done. Clearly I'm doing something wrong here, but the question is what?

```
class MultiCombo(wx.combo.ComboCtrl):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.combo.ComboCtrl.__init__(self, parent, style=wx.TE_MULTILINE)

multicombo = MultiCombo(parent_panel)
##  multicombo.SetWindowStyle(wx.TE_MULTILINE)
multicombo.GetTextCtrl().SetWindowStyle(wx.TE_MULTILINE)
multicombo.GetTextCtrl().Refresh()
multicombo.Refresh()
```

Note: code provided is a pared-down example - the actual code looks slightly different.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that according to the [documentation](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_text_ctrl.html):

> Note that alignment styles (wxTE_LEFT, wxTE_CENTRE and wxTE_RIGHT) can
>   be changed dynamically after control creation on wxMSW and wxGTK.
>   wxTE_READONLY, wxTE_PASSWORD and wrapping styles can be dynamically
>   changed under wxGTK but not wxMSW. The other styles can be only set
>   during control creation.

So rather than changing the style you need to use [wxComboCtrl::SetTextCtrlStyle](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_combo_ctrl.html#a00188332f7b6200c98f5f65966d5b151) as demonstrated in the documentation.